# How to test or substitute a frame ground point in a modern, small-motor vehicle?

Tags: batteries, ground, grounding, automotive

I have a ATV that I am trying to install a horn and light set it. Lights worked out fine but the horn worked for a bit then stopped, and now a replacement horn keeps blowing fuses. I checked and the horn get 12V when activated. Looking at the manufacturer's notes, it says that the mount need to be connected to the frame and grounded (refer to this as 'frame ground' from here out).The mount is on a non-painted screw but honestly there is so much plastic and heavily painted frame parts I am not sure it is doing the job. So here is what I am asking:

- Should I be able to measure a resistance from the battery `negative` and this screw? Should I be able to measure a slight voltage drop (if yes how much do you estimate)?
- Can I bring a fake 'frame ground' to the mount from the battery `negative`? Does this need resistance?

Comment: "horn keeps blowing fuses." How many amperes is the horn? Can the ATV battery handle that much? What is a battery "neutral"? You might run a heavy-gauge wire to both battery connectors, + and -, but you could also destroy the battery and/or start a fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Neither battery terminal should be called neutral. One terminal is positive. The other is negative. The negative one is “usually” connected to the frame/chassis. Where the battery negative is bolted to the chassis is called ground. The chassis extends the “ground” throughout the vehicle.

The term neutral applies to ac power systems.

> Should I be able to measure a resistance from the battery neutral and this screw?

Properly connected, approximately 0\$\Omega\$ should be measured. Be certain that the screw is secured.

> Can I bring a fake 'frame ground' to the mount from the battery neutral? Does this need resistance?

Yes. This is not fake, but a real connection to “frame ground”. It is a technique used where frame/chassis electrical integrity is uncertain. It can be connected to battery negative or to the point where the battery connects to the frame/chassis.

Do not use any resistance in series with the wire.

The wire diameter must be the same or greater than the positive wire supplying the voltage.

> now a replacement horn keeps blowing fuses.

Be careful that the horn positive is not somehow grounded.